# Haskell --- iterating split function over list

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary, printing, split

```
getLines = liftM lines . readFile

main = do
    argv <- getArgs
    name <- getProgName
    if not (null argv)
    then do
           let file = head argv 
           list <- getLines file
           let olist = mergesort (<=) list
           let splitter = map (split ",")  olist
           loop splitter 
    else hPutStr stderr $ "usage: " ++ name ++ " filename"

loop a = do 
    line <- getLine
    case line of
     "help"  -> putStrLn "print - prints list in alphabetical order\n\
                \quit  - exits program"
     "print" -> do putStrLn "[print]"
                   mapM_ putStrLn a
                   putStr "\n"
     "quit"  -> do putStrLn "[quit]" 
                   exitSuccess
     _       -> putStrLn "invalid command" 
    loop a
```

I'm trying to split a list of lines that each have a comma, except I get an error at, loop splitter. I think its because mapM_ putStrLn within my loop function can't understand the new list. Before i used the splitter function my program would print out the entire list taken from a text file with no problems. How can i print out a new list of words that were split at the comma?

Comment: "except I get an error at, loop splitter" - What error?

Comment: Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'         Expected type: [String]       Actual type: [[[Char]]]

Comment: Maybe you mean something like `mapM_ loop splitter`?  It looks like `splitter` is a list of lists of strings, and `loop` looks like it's expecting just a list of strings.  It would really help if you added type signatures to your functions, and even your variable declarations, they act as a sort of documentation so others can understand more about what your code is doing without having to try to compile it themselves.

Comment: is there a way to make splitter one list?

Comment: Have you tried searching [hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=[[a]]+-%3E+[a]&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09)?

Comment: not much, since im new to haskell, but ill start to. it was a really simple fix. just needed to use concat.